# Unzip a file with 7-zip (command-line) without unzipping contained zip files

Tags: command-line, zip, 7-zip

I have a zip file that contains many files, including other zip files.  I would like to extract the contents such that the extraction contains the files exactly as they are.  However, when using 7-zip from the command-line to do this, it recursively extracts every contained zip file.  I want to leave contained zip files as they are, and not extract them.

For reference, here's the command I'm using:
`7z e -oc:\util\dest -aoa myzipfile.zip`

I've been searching for solutions to this, but haven't yet found one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
7z x myzipfile.zip
```

Will extract the zip file `myzipfile.zip` without extracting containing zip files.